show that $OG \perp (A' B' C') $ and that the points $O, G$ and $H$ are collinear
The problem
Consider the tetrahedron $OABC$ in which
$OA \perp OB \perp OC \perp OA$
. A sphere with center $X$ containing the points $A, B$
and $C$ intersect the edges $OA$, $OB$, and $OC$ a second time at points $A'$, $B'$, and $C'$, respectively. If $G$
is the centroid of triangle $ABC$ and $H$ is the orthocenter of triangle $A'B'C'$, show that
$OG \perp (A' B' C') $
and that the points $O, G$ and $H$ are collinear.
drawing

my idea
Because points $A, B, C, A', B', C'$ are all on the sphere we get that $XA=XB=XC=XA'=XB'=XC'=R$, where R is the radius of the sphere
From $XA=XB=XC$ we get that the height of tetrahedron $XABC$ contains the centroid of triangle $ABC$ so $HG\perp (ABC)$
I think from here we can try expressing everything as volume...
I don't know what to do forward! I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

First we prove $OG\perp A'B'$.
We have $\overrightarrow{OG}=\frac{1}{3}(\overrightarrow{OA}+\overrightarrow{OB}+\overrightarrow{OC})$,
$\overrightarrow{OG}\cdot\overrightarrow{A'B'}=\frac{1}{3}(\overrightarrow{OA}+\overrightarrow{OB}+\overrightarrow{OC})\cdot(\overrightarrow{A'O}+\overrightarrow{OB'})=\frac{1}{3}(\overrightarrow{OA}\cdot\overrightarrow{A'O}+\overrightarrow{OB}\cdot\overrightarrow{OB'})=\frac{1}{3}(\overrightarrow{OB}\cdot\overrightarrow{OB'}-\overrightarrow{OA}\cdot\overrightarrow{OA'})=0$
from $OA, OB, OC$ are perpendicular to each other and $A,B,B',A'$ are on the same circle so $\triangle OAB\sim\triangle OB'A'$.
Similarly, $OG\perp B'C'$ and $OG\perp A'C'$.
Let's denote $H'$ as the intersection of $OG$ and $(A'B'C')$, and prove that $H'$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle A'B'C'$. Now that we have $OG\perp (A'B'C')$,  $H'$ is the projection of $O$ onto plain $(A'B'C')$, so to prove $A'H\perp B'C'$, we just need to prove that $OA'\perp B'C'$.
$\overrightarrow{OA'}\cdot\overrightarrow{B'C'}=\overrightarrow{OA'}\cdot(\overrightarrow{B'O}+\overrightarrow{OC'})=\overrightarrow{OA'}\cdot\overrightarrow{B'O}+\overrightarrow{OA'}\cdot\overrightarrow{OC'}=0$.
Similarly we can prove $B'H\perp A'C'$, $C'H\perp A'B'$. The proof that $H'$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle A'B'C'$ is complete, thus $H$ is on $OG$.

(Without using vectors:)
To prove $OG\perp B'C'$, denote $D$ as the midpoint of $BC$. $OB\perp OC$, so $OD=DB=DC$, $\angle BOD=\angle OBD=\angle OC'B'$, thus $OD\perp B'C'$. Since $OA\perp (OBC)$, $OA\perp B'C'$, thus $(OAD)\perp B'C'$, $OG\perp B'C'$. The rest goes similarly.
For the next part, just notice that $OA'\perp (OB'C')$ and $H'$ is the projection of $O$ onto $(A'B'C')$, we must have $AH'\perp B'C'$. The rest goes similarly.

Thank you so much for your idea! May I ask if there is any way to transform this idea into one without vectors? I didn't learn about them yet! Thanks again!

I added a section that doesn't use vectors. Still, I think using vectors is more convenient and intuitive.

I have one more question...How did you know that A,B,A',B' are on the same circle and how did it help you arrive at the fact those triangles are similar?

Oh, $A,B,C,A',B',C'$ are all on the sphere, and the cross section of a sphere is a circle. Then, $\angle AA'B'+\angle ABB'=\pi$, so $\angle OA'B'=\angle ABB'$, the two triangles are similar.

$\triangle OAB\sim\triangle OA'B' \implies \frac{OA’}{OA}=\frac{OB’}{OB}$; since $\vec{OB}\cdot\vec{OB’}=OB ;OB’$ and $\vec{OA}\cdot\vec{OA’}=OA ;OA’$ I cannot see how you get that $OB ;OB’ - OA ;OA’=0$

@TedBlack It's the other way round, A'->B, B'->A. Maybe I should've written $\triangle OAB\sim\triangle OB′A′$. I didn't care much about the convention, becuase usually it's not hard to tell from the context... Anyway, I fixed that in the answer.

I cannot see how you get $\triangle OAB \sim \triangle OB'A'$. You are right that $A,A',B,B'$ are concyclic and they definitely share a right angle. But why is $\angle OAB = \angle OB'A'$?
